# How don't automatically escape the "|" to "%7C"

Tags: dart

I need to read a URL, but Httpclient or Dio automatically escape the "|"  to "%7C"

This makes me always fail to read this website, but I can read the correct content through curl from the command line

Excuse me, how can I handle it so that "|" will not be escaped to "%7C" in the process of request

```
var uri = Uri(scheme: scheme, host: host, path: "abc.jpg?aaa|bbb|ccc&c=123");
var client = http.Client();
var response = await client.get(uri, headers: headers).whenComplete(client.close);
if (response.statusCode==200) {
   return response.bodyBytes;
}
throw Exception([response.headers["x-tengine-error"], response.request.url, uri.path]);
```

thx

Answer (score 1):

The character set that can be used in a URI is limited. See [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc3986.txt.pdf)

Vertical bar is not allowed and must be escaped as you have found.

If you absolutely need to have a vertical bar rather than the escaped sequence when setting up the get you will have to replace all occurences of %7C in the uri variable you have created with the vertical bar character.

However, this really should not work, or if it does it is a quirk working outside the standards.

Much better as @SmitThakkar recommends to sort this out would be to use standard characters - as they say a '-' or '_' instead. Or send the properly encoded vertical bar and get the backend code to read and interpret a URI correctly instead of expecting to see a non-standard character.

Comment: OK, thank you. It seems that it's really troublesome. I can't find a way to change the URL after calling the request. I'll look for a lower level method to deal with it,